# Perfect and Most Elegant way to deal with Duplicate entries in SQL DB

Tags: python, list, sqlite, dictionary

Alright, so here is the situation :

Let's say i have a table called "File_info" which Contains a list of all files with their matching label_set

**TABLE : FILE_INFO**

```
FILENAME                                      LABEL_NUMBER
----------------------------------------------------------------------
C:/Test_Software/6.avi                          11
C:/Test_Software/6.avi                          10
C:/Test_Software/6.avi                          8
C:/Test_Software/6.avi                          6
C:/26.avi                                       10
C:/26.avi                                       8
C:/Test_Software/Debug/Current_Frame2.avi       11
C:/Test_Software/Debug/Current_Frame2.avi       10
C:/Test_Software/Debug/Current_Frame1.avi       11
C:/Test_Software/Debug/Current_Frame1.avi       10
C:/Test_Software/26.avi                         11
C:/Test_Software/26.avi                         10
C:/Test_Software/26.avi                         9
C:/Test_Software/26.avi                         8
C:/Test_Software/26.avi                         6
```

My Goal is to achieve this structure in SQLITE Table:

```
FILENAME                                       LABEL_NUMBER
----------------------------------------------------------------------
C:/Test_Software/6.avi                          11,10,8,6
C:/26.avi                                       10,8
C:/Test_Software/Debug/Current_Frame2.avi       11,10
C:/Test_Software/Debug/Current_Frame1.avi       11,10
C:/Test_Software/26.avi                         11,10,9,8,6
```

**i.e. One file should be stored only once !!!**

So far, here are the steps that I followed to at least get the desired output :

1) Find all the Files that have duplicate Labels using SQL Query:

```
SELECT LABEL_NUMBER, FILENAME 
FROM FILE_INFO WHERE 
FILENAME 
in (SELECT FILENAME 
FROM FILE_INFO_SEARCH GROUP BY 
FILENAME HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

2) Create two list (a for file_list, b for label_list)

```
for file in find_duplicate_files: #Duplicate_Files contains the output of above SQL Query

    process_file.append(file[1])
    process_label.append(file[0])
```

3) Create a dict using pandas which will have a format as :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : process_file, 'B' : process_label})
new_dict = df.groupby('A').B.agg(','.join).to_dict()
```

So far, my output looks like this which is great:

```
C:/Test_Software/6.avi 11,10,8,6
C:/26.avi 10,8
C:/Test_Software/Debug/Current_Frame2.avi 11,10
C:/Test_Software/Debug/Current_Frame1.avi 11,10
C:/Test_Software/26.avi 11,10,9,8,6
```

But, now i am left with the final part of the challenge :

4) Implement changes in the database :

I have two thoughts here :

## Method : 1

a) Delete all duplicate entries in the Table

b) Insert all the dict key and values in Filename and Label_number column

## Method : 2

a) Simply start running a query on each 'key' value of my dict(which contains a filename) in my db, and if found, update the Label Column with the value

b) Remove duplicate entries from Table

I know there will be a third most elegant way to do this and i am looking for the same :-)

**Remember : I have a million of these records to be processed !! Both methods while work but are not efficient as i have to run several of such queries. I am looking for some short-hand answers which are fast**

Hope information that i provided will assist others out there as well !!!

Comment: Using non-atomic values in a relational schema is an antipattern. Are you sure you want to do this ???

Comment: what's the better way to handle this?

Comment: Well your original table designed is actually well normalized, which is why I wonder why you want to denormalize it.

Comment: Because, i would like to store a file only once, i don't know how better i can handle that scenario? I guess, you can assist me, please share your thought process to handle this scenario !!

Comment: Then the proper normalized solution would be to use a related table for labels with a FK on the 'file_info' table, but if all you have in the file_info table are those two fields you won't gain anything from using two tables, quite on the contrary.  Actually, the question really is about how you use those data (and why you want to "store a file only once", whatever this might mean) and what your contraints are - IOW there's not enough context to tell which design makes sense. My point was mainly to warn you that denormalization may lead to a host of problems later.